# Error in rep: attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure' (Boxplots in if statements)

Tags: r, shiny, boxplot, shiny-reactivity

I have a code that is supposed to make a boxplot maker. It is very close to working (thanks to a bunch of people on this website). The problem that I have now is that whenever I run the code, I get the `Error in rep: attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'` warning. The stack trace shows that it comes directly from the line of code that makes the boxplot (whichever one runs). Is the problem that I cannot have a boxplot inside of an if statement? I feel like that isn't true. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
All_Data <- data.frame(
    Name = as.character(c("Jeff","Bob","Greg")),
    Year = c(2015,2015,2015),
    Bacteria = c("A","B","C"),
    Site = c("C1","C1","C1"),
    Percents = c(1,2,4),
stringsasfactors = TRUE
)
ndata <-data.frame(
    Name = as.character("Preset"),
    Year = c("0"),
    Bacteria = as.factor(c("0")),
    Site = as.factor(c("0")),
    Percents = as.numeric(c("0")),
    stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)
Names <- c("Jeff", "Bob", "Greg")
Years <- c("0")
names(Years)<-c("2015 C2")
Sites <- c("","C1")
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("ISAMR DNA Group Boxplot Maker"),
    
    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                     h3("Which Data Sets Would You Like to Compare?"),
                     selectInput("Set1", "", choices = c(Sites, Years, Names)),
                     selectInput("Set2", "",choices = c(Sites, Years, Names)),
                     selectInput("factor","Based on Which Factor?", choices = c("Year", "Site", "Bacteria", "Site by Year", "Bacteria by Year", "Bacteria by Site by Year")),
                     textInput("title", h4("Title"), placeholder = "Enter title..."),
                     numericInput("numcol","How many colors?",value=1,min=1,max=5),
                     h4("Pick the colors you want, leave the rest blank."),
                     selectInput("col1","",choices = c("",colors())),
                     selectInput("col2","",choices = c("",colors())),
                     selectInput("col3","",choices = c("",colors())),
                     selectInput("col4","",choices = c("",colors())),
                     selectInput("col5","",choices = c("",colors())),
                     actionButton("Submit", "Submit")
        ),
        
        # Show a chosen plot
        mainPanel(
            #uiOutput("data"),
            DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
            plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    createframe<-eventReactive(input$Submit, {req(input$Submit)
        
        if (input$Set1 %in% Names & input$Set2 %in% Names){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name == input$Set1 | All_Data$Name == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Names & input$Set1 %in% Years){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name == input$Set1 | All_Data$Year == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Names & input$Set1 %in% Sites){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name == input$Set1 | All_Data$Site == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Years & input$Set1 %in% Names){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site == input$Set1 | All_Data$Name == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Years & input$Set2 %in% Years){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Year == input$Set1 | All_Data$Year == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Years & input$Set2 %in% Sites){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Year == input$Set1 | All_Data$Site == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Sites & input$Set1 %in% Names){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site == input$Set1 | All_Data$Name == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Sites & input$Set1 %in% Years){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site == input$Set1 | All_Data$Year == input$Set2)
        }
        else if (input$Set1 %in% Sites & input$Set1 %in% Sites){
            ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site == input$Set1 | All_Data$Site == input$Set2)
        }   })
    
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
        createframe()
    })
    observeEvent(input$numcol,{req(input$numcol)
        if (input$numcol == 1){coll<-c(input$col1)}
        if (input$numcol == 2){coll<-c(input$col1,input$col2)}
        if (input$numcol == 3){coll<-c(input$col1,input$col2,input$col13)}
        if (input$numcol == 4){coll<-c(input$col1,input$col2,input$col3,input$col4)}
        if (input$numcol == 5){coll<-c(input$col1,input$col2,input$col3,input$col4,input$col5)}
    })    
    
    observeEvent(input$factor,{req(input$factor)
        output$plot <- renderPlot(
        if (input$factor == "Year"){
                boxplot(Percents ~ Year, data = ndata, main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll)
        }
        
        else if (input$factor == "Site"){
                boxplot(Percents ~ Site, data = ndata, main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll)   
        }
        
        else if (input$factor == "Bacteria"){
                boxplot(Percents ~ Bacteria, data = ndata, main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll)
        }
        
        else if (input$factor == "Site by Year"){
                boxplot(Percents ~ Year%in%Site, data = ndata, main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll)
        }
        
        else if (input$factor == "Bacteria by Year"){
                boxplot(Percents ~ Year%in%Bacteria, data = ndata, main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll)
        }
        
        else if (input$factor == "Bacteria by Site by Year"){
                boxplot(Percents ~ Year%in%Site%in%Bacteria, data = ndata, main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll)
        }
    )})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(Not the real data)

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggrepel_0.8.2   ggthemes_4.2.0  shiny_1.5.0     dslabs_0.7.3    forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.0     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1    
[10] tidyr_1.1.0     tibble_3.0.3    ggplot2_3.3.2   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        lubridate_1.7.9   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.25     mime_0.9          R6_2.4.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.1.7  
 [9] reprex_0.3.0      httr_1.4.1        pillar_1.4.6      rlang_0.4.7       readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.11   blob_1.2.1        DT_0.14          
[17] labeling_0.3      htmlwidgets_1.5.1 munsell_0.5.0     tinytex_0.24      broom_0.7.0       compiler_4.0.2    httpuv_1.5.4      modelr_0.1.8     
[25] xfun_0.15         pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.0   sourcetools_0.1.7 tidyselect_1.1.0  fansi_0.4.1       crayon_1.3.4      dbplyr_1.4.4     
[33] withr_2.2.0       later_1.1.0.1     grid_4.0.2        jsonlite_1.7.0    xtable_1.8-4      gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_0.2.0   DBI_1.1.0        
[41] magrittr_1.5      scales_1.1.1      cli_2.0.2         stringi_1.4.6     farver_2.0.3      fs_1.4.2          promises_1.1.1    xml2_1.3.2       
[49] ellipsis_0.3.1    generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.2       tools_4.0.2       glue_1.4.1        hms_0.5.3         crosstalk_1.1.0.1 rsconnect_0.8.16 
[57] fastmap_1.0.1     yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_1.4-1  rvest_0.3.5       haven_2.3.1
```

Stack Trace:

```
Warning: Error in rep: attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
  174: pcycle
  173: bxp
  171: boxplot.default
  169: boxplot.formula
  167: renderPlot [C:\Users\pferr\Desktop\Test/app.R#102]
  165: func
  125: drawPlot
  111: <reactive:plotObj>
   95: drawReactive
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$plot
    1: runApp
```

Comment: The error usually means that you are treating a function as if it was an object. Looking at your code I'm not clear on where it's occurring, but it may go away if you remove the `observeEvent()` for the boxpot and instead store the boxplot object into a `eventReactive()` object, and then run `renderPlot()` outside of that.

Comment: Also, `Year%in%Site%in%Bacteria` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `stringsasfactors = TRUE` is wrong, should be `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`

Comment: You should not be using `&` in an `if` statement: the former suggests *"0 or more logicals"*, whereas the latter requires always length 1. It will generally work alright here, but (1) it is bad programming practice, and more important (2) it does not support logical short-circuiting (see `FALSE && stop("oops")` vs `FALSE & stop("oops")`). Same for `|` vs `||`.

Comment: Your assignment to `coll` in the `observeEvent` is unlikely to work (or, if it does seem to work then it is a bug in scope breach). Then again, you never use it ... regardless, all of those `if` statements can be reduced to `head(c(input$col1, input$col2, ...), n = input$numcol)`.

Comment: In fact, your reassignment to `ndata` is also a scope problem. You probably need to make it "reactive data".

Comment: Frankly, SamFerraro, there are so many basic R problems here with the code that I suggest you try to get this to work on the console before trying to make it work in `shiny`. Realize that `ndata <- ...` inside of a reactive/observe block is not necessarily going to update the `ndata` you define in the globals, so ... there is a lot of restructuring you need to do with this to get it to behave.

Comment: The things you have labeled as problems work perfectly well. If we could address the problem that I asked for help with, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: Even if I want to wade through all of this code, I am first confronted with `object 'coll' not found`.

Comment: And the double-`%in%` will almost certainly *not* work perfectly well. For instance, would you expect `5 %in% 0:1 %in% 0:1` to be true? It is. And I really don't know what `2015 %in% c("C1","C1") %in% c("A","B","C")` is supposed to represent (regardless of fake or real data, that's guaranteed to be `FALSE`.

Comment: I defined an empty `coll` and got your app to start without that error, and now I don't know what to do: no errors, no real plots. If you've run this exact test code (not your real code or your real data) and still see the `closure` error, then it could be an issue related to your version of R or individual packages; if that's the case, I suggest you include the output from `sessionInfo()` for comparison. If you can reproduce it with this data, this code, then please include your "setup": all of the selections you make when you click on "Submit".

Comment: When I test the code above, the only error that I get is the one I mentioned. (Nothing about `coll` even after I cleared all environments) I added the stack trace and `sessionInfo()` output above. The  `%in%` syntax  (for boxplots) is used to nest x-axis variables. So the `Year%in%Site%in%Bacteria` will make a boxplot where there are boxes for each chosen bacteria, divided up and grouped by site, and then farther divided up and grouped by year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of issues. First, color definition was an issue. A missing choice was also causing issue. So, I made it a reactive. Second, you were using ndata as data in the boxplots. Once you fix them, it works fine. Please see the code below.

```
library(shiny)

ndata <-data.frame(
  Name = as.character("Preset"),
  Year = c("0"),
  Bacteria = as.factor(c("0")),
  Site = as.factor(c("0")),
  Percents = as.numeric(c("0")),
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)
Names <- c("Jeff", "Bob", "Greg")
Years <- c("0")
names(Years)<-c("2015 C2")
Sites <- c("","C1")
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("ISAMR DNA Group Boxplot Maker"),

  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 h3("Which Data Sets Would You Like to Compare?"),
                 selectInput("Set1", "", choices = c(Sites, Years, Names)),
                 selectInput("Set2", "",choices = c(Sites, Years, Names)),
                 selectInput("factor","Based on Which Factor?", 
                             choices = c("Year", "Site", "Bacteria", "Site by Year", "Bacteria by Year", "Bacteria by Site by Year")),
                 textInput("title", h4("Title"), placeholder = "Enter title..."),
                 numericInput("numcol","How many colors?",value=1,min=1,max=5),
                 h4("Pick the colors you want, leave the rest blank."),
                 selectInput("col1","",choices = c(colors())),
                 selectInput("col2","",choices = c(colors())),
                 selectInput("col3","",choices = c(colors())),
                 selectInput("col4","",choices = c(colors())),
                 selectInput("col5","",choices = c(colors())),
                 actionButton("Submit", "Submit")
    ),

    # Show a chosen plot
    mainPanel(
      #uiOutput("data"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("data")
      ,plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  All_Data <- data.frame(
    Name = as.character(c("Jeff","Bob","Greg")),
    Year = c(2015,2015,2015),
    Bacteria = c("A","B","C"),
    Site = c("C1","C1","C1"),
    Percents = c(1,2,4),
    stringsAsFactors = TRUE
  )
  
  dframe<-reactive({
    req(input$Set1,input$Set2)

    if (input$Set1 %in% Names & input$Set2 %in% Names){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Name %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Names & input$Set2 %in% Years){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Year %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Names & input$Set2 %in% Sites){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Name %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Site %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Years & input$Set2 %in% Names){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Name %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Years & input$Set2 %in% Years){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Year %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Year %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Years & input$Set2 %in% Sites){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Year %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Site %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Sites & input$Set2 %in% Names){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Name %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Sites & input$Set2 %in% Years){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Year %in% input$Set2)
    }
    else if (input$Set1 %in% Sites & input$Set2 %in% Sites){
      ndata <- filter(All_Data, All_Data$Site %in% input$Set1 | All_Data$Site %in% input$Set2)
    }else{ndata <- NULL}
    return(ndata)
  })

  output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dframe()
  })

  coll <- reactive({
    req(input$numcol)
    if   (is.null(input$numcol)) {coll <- c("red")
    }else if (input$numcol == 1) {coll <- c(input$col1)
    }else if (input$numcol == 2) {coll <- c(input$col1,input$col2)
    }else if (input$numcol == 3) {coll <- c(input$col1,input$col2,input$col13)
    }else if (input$numcol == 4) {coll <- c(input$col1,input$col2,input$col3,input$col4)
    }else if (input$numcol == 5) {coll <- c(input$col1,input$col2,input$col3,input$col4,input$col5)
    }else                        {coll <- c("orange")}
    coll
  })

  observeEvent(input$Submit, {

    req(input$factor,input$Submit)
    if (is.null(input$factor) | input$Submit==0){
      return(NULL)
    }else{

      output$plot <- renderPlot({

        if (input$factor == "Year"){
          boxplot(Percents ~ Year, data = dframe(), main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll())
        }else if (input$factor == "Site"){
          boxplot(Percents ~ Site, data = dframe(), main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll())
        }else if (input$factor == "Bacteria"){
          boxplot(Percents ~ Bacteria, data = dframe(), main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll())
        }else if (input$factor == "Site by Year"){
          boxplot(Percents ~ Year%in%Site, data = dframe(), main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll())
        }else if (input$factor == "Bacteria by Year"){
          boxplot(Percents ~ Year%in%Bacteria, data = dframe(), main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll())
        }else if (input$factor == "Bacteria by Site by Year"){
          boxplot(Percents ~ Year%in%Site%in%Bacteria, data = dframe(), main = input$title, ylab = "Relative Abundance", col = coll())
        }else {return(NULL)}
      })

    }
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: What you did seemed to work perfectly. But I ran into the same problem after publishing it (and after clearing the global environment). I get the Warning: Error in eval: object 'Percents' not found warning. What could be causing this? Clearly, Percents is there.

Comment: Try to replace `Percents` with `dframe()$Percents` inside `boxplot` call.

Comment: That makes sense, but that produces a new error: `Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. From what I can tell, `dframe()` isn't getting updated in the published version. The `data.frame` displayed is blank with 5 columns: `V1, V2, V3, V4, V5`

Comment: @SamFerraro, There were still issues with `dframe()`.  I have made it reactive, and fixed numerous typos. Please test the updated code.

Comment: It still comes back with the `Warning: Error in eval: object 'Percents' not found` error. I really don't understand where it is coming from.

Comment: I am not sure why you have this issue. I do not see any issue when I run it on RStudio.  Perhaps you should test by not generating plot, but just printing `data` table and verify that `Percents` is still present in `dframe()`.

Comment: I think that is part of the problem. The data table that is displayed is completely blank. I don't think that it's even completing that step.

Comment: I thought you are reading in some data. If you are still using All_Data defined above ui, you need to move it inside the server so that server has access to it. Please ensure that you can print and view the data before you start plotting.

Comment: When I move it inside the server, do I need to put it in a renderDataFrame? Or just place it in?

Comment: When I run that code, it doesn't make the `dframe()` it just leaves it blank. It is the same problem that I had after publishing, but now it is happening even in RStudio.

Comment: It works either way on my RStudio. So, I am not sure. You may need to upgrade the RStudio version.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was with the `filter()` function. The format didn't work so I called `library(dplyr)` and used the `%>%` command. That fixed it. Thank you so much for all your help!